# puppeteer - identify when reCaptcha challenge becomes active/visible

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, recaptcha, chromium, invisible-recaptcha

Using this reCaptcha demo page: https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-invisible.php

Using puppeteer, my goal is to wait for and identify when the challenge (having to pick specific images from a grid) becomes visible on the page. I am NOT asking how to bypass or solve the reCaptcha, just to know when it is active and ready to be solved.

Via DevTools, I have found the HTML elements representing the visible reCaptcha challenge:
[recaptcha element tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U609g.png)

Unfortunately, I have been unable to get puppeteer to "find" the specific elements. The following code will ALWAYS print "NOT found" even when the reCaptcha is clearly visible in the browser and the `#rc-imageselect` element is visible in the element tree. I have experimented with the main frame, child frames, etc and have been unable to get puppeteer to find the reCaptcha elements.

```
let recap = await myframe.$("body #rc-imageselect")  //.rc-imageselect-payload") // #rc-imageselect
if (recap == null) {
  console.log("imageselect NOT found")
} else {
  console.log("imageselect found")
}
```

Why is this necessary? On real-world pages (not this demo page), the reCaptcha challenge won't be triggered for some users, and will only pop up for some. My goal is identify when it pops up, then choose how to handle the reCaptcha, either by solving (separately, by hand), backing off, or abandoning entirely.

Any help with puppeteer code to find the reCaptcha elements would be greatly welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use any specific args to launch Puppeteer?

Comment: @theDavidBarton in puppeteer.launch I set a `defaultViewport`, extend the `timeout`, and set `headless` to false. I have also experimented with `devTools` set to true and `sloMo` to various lengths. I've also experimented with a custom `userAgent`. This is currently in development... ultimately I would like to run this in headless mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors which never goes to the console so remains unrecognized and caused by security issues inside iframes (which is always a critical point with Chrome/Chromium browser). You will need the following security disabling args to launch puppeteer, because due to the same-origin policy you are not allowed to go inside the iframe by default.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true, args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']
})
```

These args will be always required in case of reCaptcha scenarios.

Comment: thanks so much @theDavidBarton ... as soon as I added these flags the "missing" frames became identifiable. Prior to the flags, a count of all the frames only found 2, now it is 6 I believe.

Comment: One more comment for future readers: Microsoft's `playwright` found the frames natively without needing to set any launch flags. Tested with Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go into the iframe DOM, you can figure it out by inspecting the iframe element:

```
let height = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('iframe[title="recaptcha challenge"]').offsetHeight)
```

In my experience you don't have to launch with special flags when dealing with captcha.

Comment: @pguardino this is also a terrific answer. I checked theDavidBarton's only because this one could be a bit confusing. When the iframe is not visible, it seems that it still has an offsetHeight of 150px. It increases when it becomes visible (and contains the annoying photos to check) which is the trigger needed to know whether it is visible or not. But I spent a bit of time testing for a non-zero value for offsetHeight before I figured this out. However like you said, this solution works without any extra launch flags, which is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me

`let height = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('iframe[title="recaptcha challenge"]').offsetHeight)`

but for some reason, height is always 150 unless i do

`await page.waitFor(8000)`

I'm running in headful so I can see that the captcha is visible already... but it only shows height >150 after an 8 second wait.. Very annoying